# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Although no duplicate/unwanted constraint is defined

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Title may sound a duplicate, but I have been trying to resolve it for hours, but I couldn't find any duplicate or unwanted constraint.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000491b70 UILabel:0x7fcb77544bb0'Order ID: '.centerY == UIView:0x7fcb77511c30.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004922f0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb7753fb20'12-Oct-2017, 5:51 PM']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb77547090 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492340 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb77544bb0'Order ID: ']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fcb7753fb20'12-Oct-2017, 5:51 PM']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492200 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fcb77511c30]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb77547090 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492de0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb77549a00]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb7753e4b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492f20 UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb'.top == UIView:0x7fcb77549a00.top + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492fc0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004930b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb7753e4b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004934c0 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a780]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb7754a350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493510 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a780]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb7754a350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493740 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb77547090]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb77547750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493880 V:[UIView:0x7fcb77547090]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb77548c30]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004938d0 V:[UIView:0x7fcb77548c30]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb7753e4b0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493a60 V:[UIView:0x7fcb7754a350]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb77547750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493ab0 V:[UIView:0x7fcb7753e4b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb7754a350]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493b50 V:|-(4)-[UIView:0x7fcb77547750]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcb77523ff0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000493bf0 V:[UIView:0x7fcb77547750]-(4)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcb77523ff0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000680a50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcb77523ff0.height == 68   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492fc0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']   (active)>
```

The portion of code which is generating warning is:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492f20 UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb'.top == UIView:0x7fcb77549a00.top + 8   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000492fc0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004930b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcb7753e4b0 )>",
```

But all of these 3 constraint are required to fulfil general requirements.

```
--------[View starts]-----------
---- 8 point space to top-------
[UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb']
---- 8 point space in between---
[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']
---- 8 point space to bottom----
---------[View Ends]------------
```

But following constraint is being broke to recover:

```
[UILabel:0x7fcb77549e30'Zxcvb']
---- 8 point space in between---
[UILabel:0x7fcb7754a0c0'Address, 16...']
```

But view cannot survive without this constraint.

All this is happening inside tableview cell and is happening randomly.
Also I have `IBOutlet` defined for the above constraint and it is changed to `0` or `8` for certain conditions.

The table view cell is created through XIB so it rules out to do `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: It looks like your cell height is 68 but the constraints of all the items in your cell require it to be higher than 68

Comment: I have not set the height to `68` and table cell height is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: [wtfautolayout](http://wtfautolayout.com) says otherwise

Comment: I think `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000680a50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcb77523ff0.height == 68   (active)>"` , it is being generated automatically. and wtfautolayout says `† This constraint was added by a table or collection view to enforce its cell size.`

Comment: is there any red layout icons in cell xib ???

Comment: Nope, everything is nice and blue!!

Comment: Have you assigned automatic dimension to the row height in `viewDidLoad`?  Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRow:`?

Comment: Sh_Khan's answer resolved the issue. I am still wondering why? :/

Comment: You told Autolayout that that constraint was less important, so it can break that constraint without a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'Priority' of the 'Bottom Constraint' of the bottommost item in the cell to `750` as not to conflict with **UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height**.

Comment: Is this a rule or there is some general idea behind this?  Because I can't find  any sense of doing this in the past. :/

Comment: for sorry there is no , as cell layout automatically add a height constraint to the cell when loaded that may not fit with inner constraints of the cell and that with 1000 priority ,so a constraint must be broken , but it will not harm the structure as it finally will figure out the right constraints by cell dequeuing and if you scroll you will no longer see that conflicts

Comment: I'll go with `Priority 999`.